# In JavaScript what characters is the following code replacing in mystring JS variable?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript what characters is the following code replacing in mystring JS variable?

```
 var mySecondString = myFirstString.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

Comment: Well, what do you think it does? Or what part of the code don't you understand? And what research have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking this down:

- `"` and `'` are themselves.
- `[]` means "any in the set".
- `+` indicates "one or more times" of the preceeding item.
- `g` flag means all occurrences.

Which means it is replacing all instances of `'` and `"` in the string to blanks. And as mentioned in the comments, `+` is useless since you have the `g` flag. [Read more about RegExp in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: It makes sense to mention that `+` is useless in this case.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer because of the replacement is an empty string.